# How to override datasource_url for Spring in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, spring-data

I have a problem with run service in docker-compose. Why "backend" goes to localhost if I determined SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/postgres ?

```
docker.exe compose -f C:\Users\user\Documents\netology\diploma\cloudservice\docker-compose.yaml -p cloudservice up -d
2024/02/07 23:28:21 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:default
[+] Building 2.3s (6/7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 docker:default
 => [cloudservice internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 168B                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [cloudservice internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim                                                                                                                                                                               2.2s
 => [cloudservice auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [cloudservice internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [cloudservice internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 60B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [cloudservice 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim@sha256:aaa3b3cb27e3e520b8f116863d0580c438ed55ecfa0bc126b41f68c3f62f9774                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim@sha256:aaa3b3cb27e3e520b8f116863d0580c438ed55ecfa0bc126b41f68c3f62f9774                                                                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > [cloudservice internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: changes out of order: "target/cloudservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ""
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sOVj.png)

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  cloudservice:
    container_name: cloudservice
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
  database:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
 ...
```

docekrfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

EXPOSE 5050

COPY target/cloudservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

When I run apps separately its work.